# how to extract text between a pattern in a url awk/sed/python

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to extract the plugin name and the theme name from the urls below

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.2.1
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/recent-tweets-widget/tp_twitter_plugin.css?ver=1.0
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?rev=4.6.0&amp;ver=4.2.2
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc-ie8.css
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themeforest-9412083-specular-responsive-multipurpose-business-theme/specular/style.css?ver=4.2.2
```

i tried awk and sed both. couldn't get desired results.

Comment: post your attempts along with expected output.

Comment: So where exactly is the theme and plugin for each string? They all seem to be different.

Answer (score 1):

### sed

Use this [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command:

```
 sed  's/.*\(plugin\|theme\)s\/\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\2/'
```

It looks for the first occurrence of either `plugins` or `themes`, followed by a slash (`/`). Next it takes a series of non slashes (`[^\/]*`) followed by a slash. This sequence is put in a group `\(\)` and reinserted at the substitution `\2`.

Example usage:

```
$ cat file 
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.2.1
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/recent-tweets-widget/tp_twitter_plugin.css?ver=1.0
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?rev=4.6.0&amp;ver=4.2.2
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc-ie8.css
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themeforest-9412083-specular-responsive-multipurpose-business-theme/specular/style.css?ver=4.2.2
new2, 2.2.2.2, myweb2.com
$ sed  's/.*\(plugin\|theme\)s\/\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\2/' file
contact-form-7
recent-tweets-widget
revslider
js_composer
themeforest-9412083-specular-responsive-multipurpose-business-theme
```

### awk

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is actually even easier, just set the field separator to a slash and print the sixth field.

```
awk -F '/' '{ print $6 }' file
```

Which yields the same result as the above [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple python approach

```
with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        print url.split('/')[5]
```